# ASP.NET HttpGet supported return types from methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm creating an asp.net core 2.0 webapi project, using the default sample produced from 'dotnet new webapi'.

In the default GET method created for you I can see the Get method is happy to return a value type and an IEnumerable, but what return types are supported 'out of the box' to respond to the typical accept header types. I've searched, but I simply cannot find a thing.

e.g.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Searching I can can also see you can return an IActionResult for which you can use Ok and JSon methods to return data using the default accept header or directly as json.

But

1. Where do I find a definitive list of what can and cannot be sent
   back?
2. Why is IEnumerable working (this is really me not knowing what is and isn't a valid return type)?

This is my typical frustrating story with ASP.Net, articles don't tell me answers properly, they are dated from 2013 and out of date and are no long valid, and I just keep going round in circles. I have no idea whether I'm reading about core 2, core 1, full dotnet, mvc 5, mvc 6, and they're all different. It's so much easier with Java :(

thanks.

Comment: You can return anything you want as long as you can serialise it (e.g. JSON/XML)

Comment: Cheers. I'm just getting confused by all these articles and stackoverflow questions that seem to be correct but then are completely wrong because they are for a different implemention of webapi, mvc, etc and it's hard to find answers for the current base using .net core..

Comment: I would suggest less vitriol when talking about a particular tech though. Many people use and adore .Net and won't be inclined to help when you call it frustrating and say something else is better! Having said that, PHP is rubbish...

Answer (score 1):

The return type for all actions is `IActionResult`. That could be satisfied by any number of different things, whether actual `*Result` types (`ViewResult`, `ContentResult`, `JsonResult`, `FileResult`, etc.) or anything that can be converted into a `*Result` type. For example, returning a string typically results in a `ContentResult`, whereas returning an object will typically cause the serializer to kick off to return a `JsonResult` with the object serialized into JSON.

Long and short, you can pretty much return *anything* from an action. The framework is pretty smart about creating an appropriate result object from whatever you return. In situations where you *know* exactly what you want returned, you should return that. For example, if you always want JSON, then return `Json(obj)` rather than `obj`. However, if you want to be agnostic about it (return JSON *or* XML), then return the object directly, and let the framework pick the appropriate serializer.

Just an additional note regarding your confusion with what you're reading: there is only ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC. MVC only goes up to major version 5. When you see MVC 6 referenced, it's actually ASP.NET Core, but back when it was still a *very* early pre-release. So many things changed on the way to 1.0, that anything that references MVC 6 should be considered completely useless at this point. Core 2.0 made a lot of major breaking changes to Core 1.0, so in general, anything you see reference Core 1.X at this point should be taken when a very large grain of salt. There *may* be useful information, but more likely than not, it's not accurate any more. Therefore, if you're looking for info on ASP.NET Core, look for 2.0. If it's any other lesser version, use it only if you can't find better info, and then, be prepared for things to not work quite as described. Again, avoid MVC 6 info altogether. Previous versions of MVC refer to the still available ASP.NET MVC, not Core, and won't be any help to you at all if you're trying to build a Core app.

Finally, full .NET or "the full framework", is mostly referenced in Core 1.X -themed articles and tutorials. At that time, .NET Core 1.X had a comparatively small API footprint, so usage of a lot of different libraries would require running on the full framework rather than Core (You could still build an ASP.NET Core web app - it just wouldn't actually target .NET Core). However, .NET Core 2.0 implements .NET Standard 2.0, which brings near complete API parity with the full framework (with the exception of mostly Windows-specific APIs). As a result, you can reference virtually any .NET library with .NET Core 2.0, now.